# Ugrade minimist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, package

recently I've been getting this error message on github

```
Upgrade minimist to version 0.2.1 

high severity
Vulnerable versions: < 0.2.1
Patched version: 0.2.1
minimist before 1.2.2 could be tricked into adding or modifying properties of Object.prototype using a "constructor" or "proto" payload.
```

Im not too sure why I'm getting this error. I never installed the minimist package before. I just created my project from `create-react-app`.

Is this something I should be worried about? If it is, how do i fix it?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
npm ls minimist
```

you will see which of your installed packages has a dependency on minimist. Most likely they will be dev packages that only run while building your project. Unless you will be deploying these packages, the security warning is not something you should worry about.

Here is more information about this warning for Angular apps. It most likely holds for React apps also: [Upgrade minimist to >=1.2.3](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36104#issuecomment-600564245)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a dependency that is using it. You should check your `package-lock.json` and see which one it is.